# RoR - Filtering models by results of methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method on my model, a `Case` called `stats` that calculates and returns hash with statistics about the model. How can I make a query that filters by the results of that method? (For example, if I want to see all of the results where all Cases have a win percentage over 50)

All of the stuff on scopes that I find online has to do with filtering by different attributes of the model

Comment: You need to express what `stats` does in SQL so that you can use that logic inside the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case you can use the select method.

```
Case.select{|c| c.stats[:win_percentage] > 50 }
```

if stats is instance method

Comment: It's worth noting that this will retrieve the entire table and execute the block for each row, which may not be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're dealing with an ActiveRecord model.
If win_percentage is a column, as seems to be the case, you could do:

```
Case.where("win_percentage > 50")
```

This is more efficient than simply using the select method as you let the DB do the filtering.

But if you need to filter on a method which can't be expressed as a where condition (ie. can't be performed by the DB), then yes, you'd need to resort to the .select {} approach. (In that case, if you have a lot of results, you might want to use .find_in_batches()).

Comment: It's not a column. I do have wins and losses as a column, though. Would it be more efficient to write up a bare SQL query that calculates the average?

Comment: If you have a lot of data, you might consider adding columns for those stats and then adding callbacks (or db triggers) to populate them. That way you'd avoid having to calculate the stats on the fly each time.